# Select an element after appending it in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I appended an element:

```
$("#usernames_list").append("<li class='username_item'>" + item.username + "</li>")
```

Then I tried to select the newly appended element:

```
$(".username_item").bind('click', function(){
    alert("asdas");
})
```

tried this also:

```
$(".username_item").click(function(){
    alert("asdas);
})
```

alert function is not working.

How to fix this? All those other answers did not help

Comment: Your code should work (see working example [here][1]):

I'd suggest you have a check at the order in which you inject and then bind your element.

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/3djh7zsh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work as is but is not very effective.

Simplest and most effective way would be to keep reference of your created element so you won't have to research it again:

```
var $container = $("<li class='username_item'>" + item.username + "</li>");
$container.appendTo($("#usernames_list"));
```

this way you can register your listener easily :

```
$container.click(function(){
    alert("asdas");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it this way:

```
var $container = $("#usernames_list");
var liClick = function() {
    alert("ok");
}

$container.on('click', '.username_item', liClick);
```

And here is example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/scg32rzh/3/